# How to find the number of keys created in map part?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to write Spark application that would find me the number of keys that has been created in the `map` function. I could find no function that would allow me to do that.

One way I've thought of is using accumulator where I'd add 1 to the accumulator variable in the `reduce` function. My idea is based on the assumption that accumulator variables are shared across nodes as counters.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking something like the Hadoop counters in spark, the most accurate approximation is an Accumulator that you can increase in every task, but you do not have any information of the amount of data that Spark has processed so far.

If you only want to know how many distinct keys do you have in your rdd, you could do something like a count of the distinct mapped keys (rdd.map(t=>t_1)).distinct.count)

Hope this will be useful for you